XSRF TOKEN with Angular
I'm learning to use Angular 18 without standalone but I got some problems when I decided to use Laravel on the backend, and yeah it is a problem using CSRF token in the post, put, and delete requests.
I´m using Sanctum in laravel and all the config files are ready to use CORS, but I don't know why laravel rejects all my requests with a "CSRF token mismatch".
Now I have in angular the next service.
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Csrf } from "./csrf.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class DataCSRF{
    tokenActual:string = '';
    private csrfUrl = 'http://localhost:8088/sanctum/csrf-cookie';
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

    getCsrfToken(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.csrfUrl}`, {withCredentials: true});
    }

    getCookie(name: string): string {
        const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
        if (match) {
            return match[2];
        }
        return '';
    }
}

I generate that getCookie() method because angular doesn't generate automatically the X-XSRF-TOKEN header request.
Now, that getCsrfToken() is executed in the ngOnInit of my app.componente.ts so it makes the cookie of XSRF-TOKEN: image of that request with cookie correctly placed
So now. when I want to make a request like this for example
updateRole(role:Role){
        //Get the token placed in the cookie
        let token = this.csrf.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

        //Prepare the header to be placed in the request
        let headers = {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
        };
        
        //Prepare the data to be sended
        let peticion = {
            name: role.name,
            description: role.description
        };

        //Execute the request
        this.http.post(`${this.url}/edit/role/${role.id}`, peticion, {headers, withCredentials: true}).subscribe(
            {
                next: (data) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: (error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        );
    }

When I make that request I get the next error, see the next image please:
Error of the request
But I don't know why I'm getting that error, in my headers are the X-XSRF-TOKEN and the Cokie, so the request may be working right?, watch the next image to see that my headers are correct: Headers of my request
Somebody explain to me why this is happening? or what are my errors. I'm new to using Angular.

To me it looks like you are placing headers that is an dict inside another dict and that create all problems, try to place withCredintials inside headers and see if it helps

Make sure the backend is checking for the correct custom header... btw, it'll also help if you use HttpClientXsrfModule...  ex: (in app.module.ts:  HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
headerName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'
})   The cookieName is the cookie it will read each time... the headerName is the name of the custom-header to send it as.  It'll do this on each request as long as you use relative paths.  Your back-end may be expecting another cookie in the request... (the true anti-csrf value)  It depends on how that framework handles things.

also be sure to have an authenticated session.  The token will be tied to the session.

Technically if you just require a custom header to be set (it can be anything) for every request and don't allow cross-site requests you should be safe from CSRF attacks.  Every JS request would require a pre-flight check.

btw, the first screenshot shows that laravel sets the cookie to something different than what you send later.  Something's wrong when you go to read that cookie... you should probably just use the HttpClientXsrfModule and it'll take care of it.  Also be sure to re-hit that Laravel endpoint after logging in as the session should change (else you'd be vulnerable to session-fixation).  Then that endpoint will set/update the XSRF-TOKEN cookie and you can read it again.

Thanks for your comments dudes, i try to debug the code of sanctum and idk but it was the problem, i had a bug when it attemp to get the cookies from a request, so i decided to disable csrf in development so now when i want to do a deploy on production i'll use Laravel to add my project  of angular inside, so i will use of csrf token with the same domain and i don´t need to use sanctum more, the bug of sanctum was really weird idk if it now is incompatible with the last version of laravel.
